# Woocommerce Email attachments not working - file not being attached

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I overrided Woocommerce admin-new-email.php with some custom meta, in addition, I have added a filter to add attachment file from an ACF options page file field.

```
function attach_order_notice ( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Only for "New Order" email notification (for admin)
    error_log( 'attachments: '. print_r( get_field( 'email_file_attachment', 'options' )['url'], true ) );

    //if( $email_id == 'new_order' ){
        $attachments[] = get_field( 'email_file_attachment', 'options' )['url'];
    //}
    return $attachments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_order_notice', 10, 3 );
```

When I check the log I get a URL to a PDF file and is viewable, when I receive the email there is no file attached, not to admin email nor customer email.

What could be the reason?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Woocommerce need a local path and not a URL to the file. In order to fix I used this:

```
function attach_order_notice ( $attachments, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Only for "New Order" email notification (for admin)

    //if( $email_id == 'new_order' ){
        $file_path = wp_upload_dir()['path'];
        $file_name = get_field( 'email_file_attachment', 'options' )['filename'];
        $attachments[] = $file_path . '/' . $file_name;
    //}
    return $attachments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_order_notice', 10, 3 );
```

I hope this helps someone.